# Problem with finding prime numbers in range

Tags: python

**Program description:**

> Program accepts a segment of N numbers, [1024, 289213] in my case. Then it should output a summ of all prime numbers within this segment.

**My solution:**

```
for i in range(1024, 289213):
    isPrime = True
    for j in range(2, i // 2):
        if (i % j) == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
    if isPrime:
        n += i
print(n)
```

**Problem:** The program works perfectly with small segments, like [3,17], however in case of [1024, 289213] it takes forever to load.

What could be the source of the problem? Maybe there's even a better way to code this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think about how many combinations have to be checked, then you might know why it takes a long time. There are more efficient algorithms for identifying prime numbers, maybe you find a better solution.

Comment: Additionally, loops in Python are quite slow. If that's a possibility to you, writing the same algorithm in C or almost every other language will result in much smaller runtimes. Python libraries like `numba` will also help to speed up your code.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch thank you for your suggestion, but in this particular task it is required to use vanilla Python)

Comment: Then another, more efficient algorithm is probably the way to go. Changing the inner loop to a combination of `any` and a generator expression might also help. And you can parallelize the outer loop using `multiprocessing`, but that's a rather large change. The [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set of codes will solve the problem you are facing:

```
from math import sqrt 

# Function to compute the prime number 
# Time Complexity is O(sqrt(N)) 
def checkPrime(numberToCheck) : 

    if numberToCheck == 1 : 
        return False

    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(numberToCheck)) + 1) : 

        if numberToCheck % i == 0 : 
            return False

    return True

def primeSum(l, r) : 

    sum = 0

    for i in range(r, (l - 1), -1) : 

        # Check for prime 
        isPrime = checkPrime(i) 
        
        if (isPrime) : 

            # Sum the prime number 
            sum += i 

    return sum

# Time Complexity is O(r x sqrt(N)) 
 
if __name__ == "__main__" : 

    l, r = 1024, 289213

    # Call the function with l and r 
    print(primeSum(l, r))
```

Output:

```
3463762527
```

Please note that it will take a few seconds to get the output.

Comment: This just changes the upper limit for `i` from `i//2` to `int(sqrt(i))+1`, right?